# Как подключиться к сервису запущенном на виртуальной машине

Tags: virtualbox, openshift

Запустил на виртуальной машине (Ubuntu Server) кластер Openshift. При запуске он мне дает ip address к примеру 192.133.22.1:8443/console. Как открыть этот адрес у себя на компьютере (то есть напрямую)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попытаться открыть через браузер. В документации написано, что так можно:

> The OpenShift Container Platform web console is a user interface accessible from a web browser. 
> Developers can use the web console to visualize, browse, and manage the contents of projects.

Comment: Это же убунту сервер. Поэтому там нет графической оболочки